# Log4j Configuration and Properties in Tomcat8 in Production

Tags: tomcat, log4j, tomcat8

I am running tomcat in the Ubuntu. I wanna configure Log4j in the Tomcat for my application log. I wanna create my log like
/log/applicationname/yyyyMMddapplicationname.log.

For this reason 
1) What configuration do I need to change in the Tomcat?
2) What will be the properties file of the Log4j?
3) What code do I need to add in my Java application?

Comment: You can do this without modifying Tomcat at all. Just use log4j as usual in your own application with the `log4j.jar` file in `WEB-INF/lib`. If you want help with log4j, read the log4j documentation.

Comment: This Log4J properties file is working fine in Dev environment. But its not working in Production.

Comment: # Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, stdout

Comment: # Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=/home/user/Desktop/DevelopmentforLinux/userloginhistoryapi/log/userloginhistoryapi.log
#log4j.appender.file.File=${catalina.base}/userloginhistoryapi/userloginhistoryapi.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=100MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

Comment: I have added the log4J properties code. Please suggest..

Comment: You need to read the documentation for log4j if you want to use it properly. SO is not a group of executive assistants who read things for you.

Comment: The following code is working for me.                                                                                            
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, stdout, DEBUG, RollingAppender

log4j.appender.RollingAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.File=userloginhistoryapi.log
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

Comment: Its working on my end.